# create a subplot of multiple histograms with titles

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, subplot

I have a dataframe with a column named "CityName" with repeated names of cities and another column named "CarTripDuration" showing multiple car trip events. I want to create a histogram per city showing the car trip duration.

The following code generates a histogram per city in a separate plot with the same title (i.e., CarTripDuration). However, I would like all histograms in a singe plot (e.g., 10 rows by 5 columns) and each plot having the title of the city that the histogram corresponds to.

`ax = data.groupby(['CityName']).hist(column='CarTripDuration')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a loop like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': np.random.choice(['London', 'Paris', 'Madrid', 'Berlin'], size=N),
                   'CarTripDuration': np.random.randint(10, 100, N)})

# Create subplots 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Distributions of CarTripDuration by City')

# Generate histograms
for ax, (name, subdf) in zip(axes.flatten(), df.groupby('City')):
    subdf.hist('CarTripDuration', ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(name)

plt.show()
```

[image: Distributions of CarTripDuration by City]

**Update:**

To use `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
```

Replace `subdf.hist(...)` by:

```
sns.histplot(subdf, x='CarTripDuration', ax=ax)
```

[image: Seaborn]

Comment: How could I change the code to use sns.distplot()? ```for ax, (name, subdf) in zip(axes.flatten(), data_new.groupby('City')):
    sns.distplot(data_new['CarTripDuration'])
    ax.set_title(name)```

Comment: `distplot` is deprecated, use `displot` instead but you can't because the function doesn't accept `ax` parameter. You have to use `histplot`.

Comment: It works for me. I think you have no column `CarTripDuration`